# How can I put an actionlistener to the OK button of JOptionpane.showInputDialog?

Tags: java, actionlistener, joptionpane, fileoutputstream

I have a showInputDialog. Whenever I type something to that field, I want it to be save as textfile when I click the ok button. My problem is I don't know where/how to put the listener.

Could somebody help me about this matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The saving code shouldn't be in the `InputDialog` context, but in your code. `InputDialog` is just a way to prompt for data.

```
String whatHeTyped = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type something...");
saveToFile(whatHeTyped);
```

Comment: yeah I can save now but there's a problem, it only save 6 characters above when I type to the field and click the ok button.

Comment: It doesn't make sense, if you output the whatHeTyped variable in System.out.println(), it'll show you the exact String you've Input. I believe the problem is in the savingToFile code in your program. Can you update your question showing that code?

Comment: its ok now, sorry for the late reply. Thanks...!

Answer (score 2):

No need to add actionListener just check variable value associated with JOptionPane.

<del>Something like this:int i = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "hi","Test Message",
JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
System.out.println(i);
if(i==0){
/// OK is clicked.
}</del>

To check for input dialog do as follows:

```
    String i = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("hi");
    System.out.println(i!=null);
```

If user has pressed `OK` then `i` will be not null even if he has not entered anything in textbox. For `Cancel` button `i` will be null.

Comment: He is talking about InputDialog, not Confirm.

Comment: @EvertonAgner : My fault didn't seen it. Updated the answer.

Comment: @Harry yeah I can save now but there's a problem, it only save 6 characters above when I type to the field and click the ok button.

Comment: I doubt it only saves 6 characters. This would be a problem with your code and we are not mind readers. Post your SSCCE that demonstrates this problem.